# HTML/CSS: Is there a way to specify a minimum parent height before a child element displays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using BootStrap and jQuery, so answers using these will also suffice.

Essentially, I have dropdown lists and I'm inserting two **spans** within the **ul**s to mark the top and bottom of the list. They appear fine, and they scroll when the list scrolls, but I *only* want them to appear if the list overflows creating the scrollbar. Is there a simple CSS trick to do that, or should I just use a jQuery to check if the list can scroll and update its position, then?

Edit. People wanted code, as bare-bones as this is.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">SubMenu 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <span class="menu-anchor-top"></span>
        <span class="menu-anchor-bottom"></span>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post your code, please?

Comment: Sharing some markup would definitely help.

Comment: Yep , you can specify a ** min-height:%;   **

Comment: What the heck is the deal with people downvoting a question?  I don't see the point of getting all butt-hurt because a question doesn't seem worth of your lofty knowledge.  I understand that for some people, SO is a points and badges game.  But, let's not lose sight of the fact that for the vast majority of us, SO is a LEARNING experience.  If you don't like the question, go somewhere else.  If the question is truly counter-productive, or isn't a question, or is constructed in such a way that it cannot be answered, then maybe a downvote is worthy.  But, c'mon.  I come here to LEARN.

Comment: Thanks @Sachin; both your solution and @Puzzle84's solution work. I'll be going with Sachin's since I wanted to handle this with CSS.

Comment: @freestock.tk and BenM I've given you markup that can replicate my scenario. Does this help?

Comment: When i paste this code on a playground with bootstrap nothing shows up. [**click**](http://www.bootply.com/D1mhaFW97C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to do this with min-height.
but commenter above seems to know it works.

This however should do the trick.
The scrollWidth will be bigger than the outerWidth if you have a scrollbar.

```
if ( $("element").outerHeight() < $("element").get(0).scrollHeight ) {
    console.log("we have a scrollbar!");
    //show your stuff.
}
```

//EDIT: obviously it has to be outerHeight instead of width.